# Join vs mapping with a dictionary to add new data to a Pandas/PySpark dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas, pyspark

I have a big dataframe with a weather column that can take 5 different values (sunny, cloudy, rain, snow and other). I have to add another column with more information that depends solely on the weather value (eg. if it is a sunny day, add the value x to the new column, if it is a cloudy day add the value y, ...).

I'm wondering what is a "better" approach (more "standard" approach) for doing this. Either making a join with another small dataframe that has the weather column (join on this column) and a "new_data" column with these new values to be added (5 rows and 2 columns), or mapping each row of the dataframe with a dictionary with the weather values as keys and the new data to be added as values. An example of this last approach is shown below:

```
new_data = {"sunny": x, "cloudy": y, "rain": z, "snow": m, "other": n}

# Pandas
df["new_column"] = df["weather"].apply(lambda x: new_data[x])

# PySpark
from pyspark.sql.functions import udf, col
from pyspark.sql.types import FloatType
add_weather_data_f = udf(lambda x: new_data[x], FloatType())
df = df.withColumn("new_column", add_weather_data_f(col("weather")))
```

Which one is a "better" approach when working with a Pandas dataframe or a PySpark dataframe?

Comment: broadcast join with a small df sounds like a possible approach with spark

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Dont see a reason for a **`join`** here. Broadcast will be fast but I like to avoid joins wherever I can when working with big data.

```
from pyspark.sql import functions as F

new_data=(['sunny','x'],['cloud','y'],['rain','z'],['snow','m'],['other','n'])
new_data1=(F.when(F.col('weather')==(x[0]), F.lit(x[1])) for x in new_data)
df.withColumn('new_column', F.coalesce(*new_data1)).show(truncate=False)

+-------+----------+
|weather|new_column|
+-------+----------+
|sunny  |x         |
|cloud  |y         |
|rain   |z         |
|snow   |m         |
|other  |n         |
+-------+----------+
```

Comment: Thank you for your response. Please, correct me if I'm wrong. In your code, with new_data1 you are generating all the comparisons of all the weather variables, and then taking the one that matches and has no NaN value. Isn't it more efficient to directly search for the actual value in a dictionary (or pandas df, list of tuples, ...) with the help of a UDF (and thus, you avoid the execution time of the coalesce function)?